# Spring Data CrudRepository Method to search by object nested in object saved in array

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class **Profile** that has a **SkillLevel list** and SkillLevel has a **Skill** which has a **String: name** property.

I want to get profiles that have SkillLevels with Skills whose names contain a given string. For example, profiles that have "C#" or "Java" (or even "Ja" should work as well) as Skills.

For illustration, a JSON Get of a profile gives me the following code:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "tenure": "Tenure1",
    "seniority": "Junior Developer",
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "JTP",
            "start": "2020-12-31",
            "end": "2020-11-02"
        }
    ],
    "developer": {
        "id": 14,
        "fullName": "Dev Name",
        "age": 25
    },
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "skill": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "C#"
            },
            "level": {
                "level": "low"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Profile class:

```
@Entity public class Profile {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String tenure;
private String seniority;
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Project> projects;
@ManyToMany
private Collection<SkillLevel> skillLevels;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Developer developer;

}
```

SkillLevel class:

```
@Entity public class SkillLevel {
@Id
private long id;
@ManyToOne
private Skill skill;
@ManyToOne
private Level level;
```

Skill class:

```
@Entity public class Skill {
@Id
private long id;
private String name;
```

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to write this CrudRepository method. If possible I'd like to avoid writing the query myself.

The following is one of the methods I tried:

```
public List<Profile> findAllBySkillLevelsContainingSkill_NameContains(String str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in this case:

```
List<Profile> findProfilesBySkillLevels_SkillNameIgnoreCaseContains(String string);
```